# XML serialize and deserialize - how to don't give specific type?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have nice piece of code:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(variableList.GetType());
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(variable))
    serializer.Serialize(writer, variableList);

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<variable>));
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(variable))
    variableList = (List<variable>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

This code have to serialize and deserialize some specific List based on a specific variable and its type. It can be written in two methods. My question is, how can I make two methods with this code, that they would not need any specific variable and/or type, so that the methods (assuming the serialization would be possible) would be universal? I can use object type and T.

Comment: "that they would not need any specific variable and/or type" - but: `XmlSerializer` needs to know the type. What can be assumed? If generics are an option, then just `typeof(T)` or `typeof(List<T>)`...? Otherwise: reflection: `typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type)`

Comment: Ok. I think about method definition. Is there a way that I would not have to specify the type, so the method would be universal but the Serializer would know what type it is?

Comment: Maybe I could pass the type to the method? Something like: `(object obj, Type type)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Any type can be used. Collections and object also.

Methods:

```
static void SerializeToXml<T>(string file, T value)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(file))
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
}

static T DeserializeFromXml<T>(string file)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(file))
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Class:

```
public class Test
{
    public int i;
    public string s;
}
```

Invocation:

```
var test = new List<Test> { new Test() { i = 1, s = "jeden" }, new Test() { i = 2, s = "dwa" } };
SerializeToXml("test.xml", test);
test = null;
test = DeserializeFromXml<List<Test>>("test.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tweaked version of your [old deserialize version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21785820/2) so you don't need to type so much on invocation.

```
static List<T> DeserializeXmlToList<T>(string file)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(file))
        return (List<T>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Invocation:

```
var test = new List<Test> { new Test() { i = 1, s = "jeden" }, new Test() { i = 2, s = "dwa" } };
SerializeListToXml("test.xml", test);
test = null;
test = DeserializeXmlToList<Test>("test.xml");
```

You can also tweak the input so it will only accept `List<T>` types

```
static void SerializeToXml<T>(string file, List<T> value)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(file))
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
}
```

Comment: Too late! I was first! ;)